# How to draw a texture to the screen without using shader in OpenGL 3.3 or above?

Tags: opengl, shader, textures, opengl-3

Is there any way to draw a texture to the screen without using a shader? Something like the immediate mode in gl3.1 (glBegin, glTexCoord, etc). I know that VA and IB are necessary but what about the shader? I've just needed to show a simple texture fullscreen.

Comment: You can't (except framebuffer blit). However when you use a compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) you can still use `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences.

Comment: @Rabbid76 can you tell me more about framebuffer blit?

Comment: No, this is a bad idea. [`glBlitFramebuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBlitFramebuffer.xhtml) is not intended to draw geometry. You would have to create a framebuffer with a texture attachment and _blit_ on the default framebuffer. If you want to learn OpenGL, you need to learn about Shaders. I recommend to read a good tutorial. e.g. [LearnOpenGL - Shaders](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Shaders). If you don't want to learn anything about shaders, stick with immediate mode and use `glBegin`/`glEnd` or fixed function attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically no. The proper OpenGL 3 way is to make a shader.